# Why would just two bits of the SP be used here?

Tags: disassembly, linux, arm, kernel

This is the section of disassembled code in question. It’s from a Linux kernel module compiled for 4.4.16 on ARMv7.

```
  ; Registers used:
  ;  - r3 :  unsigned long argp

0000005c         mov        r1, sp
00000060         bic        r2, r1, #0x1fc0
00000064         bic        r2, r2, #0x3f
00000068         ldr        r4, [r2, #0x8]
0000006c         adds       r1, r3, #0x1
00000070         sbcslo     r1, r1, r4
00000074         movlo      r4, #0x0
00000078         cmp        r4, #0x0
0000007c         bne        loc_dc
```

The stack at this point looks like this:

```
00  <- SP
04  [padding]
07  u8 arg_kernel
08  pushed[r4]
0c  pushed[r5]
10  pushed[r6]
14  pushed[lr]
18  <Previous SP>
```

Here’s how I decoded this assembly into pseudo-C:

```
r4 = *(SP & 0xe000 + 8);
r1 = argp + 1;

if (r1 overflowed) {
    r1 -= r4;
    r4 = 0;
}

if (r4 == 0) {
  /* jump */
}
```

If I got this right, I don’t really understand the purpose of this code. If I made a mistake, I *really* don’t understand it. Can anyone offer any insight into the purpose of these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is wrong. The two BIC instructions clear the 13 low bits of the stack pointer (1FC0|3F = 1FFF). In kernel mode, this produces a pointer to the [`thread_info` structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43176500) for the current thread.

The `ldr` then reads the field at offset 8 in it which [seems to be `addr_limit`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3/source/arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h) and `r3+1` apparently should not exceed it.

Combined, the code matches this helper from `uaccess.h`:

```
#define __range_ok(addr, size) ({ \
    unsigned long flag, roksum; \
    __chk_user_ptr(addr);   \
    __asm__("adds %1, %2, %3; sbcccs %1, %1, %0; movcc %0, #0" \
        : "=&r" (flag), "=&r" (roksum) \
        : "r" (addr), "Ir" (size), "0" (current_thread_info()->addr_limit) \
        : "cc"); \
    flag; })
```